# Install deluge daemon through apt-get only?

Tags: server, deluge

Okay so here is where I'm at, I have already run this:

```
sudo apt-get install deluged deluge-webui
```

and when I typed in `deluged` it starting running the dameon

I guess my question is where do I go from here? How do I get the web-ui running and how can I make sure they all start when the entire server is restarted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You also need to start `deluge-web`. Or `deluge-web --fork` if you want the process to be started in the background. Then open a browser.

Go to

```
http://localhost:8112
```

Password should be `deluge`.

[image]

If you want it started at boot time you need to folllow [this](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/InitScript/Ubuntu%2011.04+%20%28Upstart%20Job%29).

Answer (score -1):

Check this easy to follow guide for Deluge installation:

http://linuxblog.avserver.info/install-deluge-with-webui-on-ubuntu-1204-precise-pangolin-server/

Worked for me on Ubuntu Server 12.04 Precise.

Comment: The link is broken. It would be great if you could update the link as well as provide a synopsis of the article in this answer