# What daemon torrent clients are available on Ubuntu?

Tags: bittorrent

I'm looking for a daemon torrent client for my server, which is running Ubuntu 12.04. I want to be able to connect to this client from my laptop, which is also running Ubuntu 12.04, preferably with a GUI, but a CLI interface would be OK too.

What daemon torrent clients are available on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5):

Allmost all GNU/Linux torrents have daemons these days. I use Transmission on my server at home (it is also the default torrent client installed on the desktop), but you can also use Deluge, uTorrent and many others.

- [Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/)

  - Uses fewer resources than other clients
  - Native Mac, GTK+ and Qt GUI clients
  - **Daemon ideal for servers, embedded systems, and headless use**
  - All these can be remote controlled by Web and Terminal clients
  - Local Peer Discovery
  - Full encryption, DHT, µTP, PEX and Magnet Link support
- [Deluge server install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139896/install-deluge-daemon-through-apt-get-only) topic on AU.

> Deluge is a full-featured  BitTorrent client for Linux, OS X, Unix and Windows. It uses  libtorrent in its backend and features multiple user-interfaces including: GTK+, web and console. **It has been designed using the client server model with a daemon process that handles all the bittorrent activity**. The Deluge daemon is able to run on headless machines with the user-interfaces being able to connect remotely from any platform.

- [uTorrent server install](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/09/utorrent-is-finally-available-for-linux.html). Old but should still work and a [start up script](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/start-utorrent-server-as-daemon-with.html) (if still needed).

You might also be interested in [flexget](http://flexget.com/). It can be used with programs that use aw watch-directory (all 3 mentioned above do).

> FlexGet is a multipurpose automation tool for content like torrents, nzbs, podcasts, comics, series, movies, etc. It can use different kinds of sources like RSS-feeds, html pages, csv files, search engines and there are even plugins for sites that do not provide any kind of useful feeds.